# Have div within a fixed div catch mouse clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-bubbling, stoppropagation

I'm using a slightly modified version of this modal window: http://blog.avtex.com/2012/01/26/cross-browser-css-only-modal-box/

One of the modifications I've made is to add `onclick="history.back(-1)"` to the overlay and vertical-offset divs in order to hide the modal by clicking outside of it.  However, adding the onclick event to the vertical-offset div catches clicks that occur on the dumbBox div.

You can take a look at this jsFiddle to see what's happening: http://jsfiddle.net/dvrcthewrld/uaP3v/1/

*How can I get the dumbBox div to catch those clicks that occur within it, rather than the vertical-offset div catching them?*

[No jQuery, please.]

I'd really love to know why the inner div passes on the click event to the parent and how to stop that.

Comment: you want the modal to close when the user clicks outside dumbBox?

Comment: Yes, and I want that to happen by triggering a history back event.  I'm generally happy with my solution.  It's just the pesky issue with the vertical-offset div that makes it imperfect.

Comment: Might `stopPropagation` be appropriate here?

Answer (score 1):

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cZkn2/**

html

```
<div class="vertical-offset" onclick="check(this)">
    <div class="dumbBox" id="div">
        Content goes here<br/>
        Content goes here<br/>
        Content goes here<br/>
        Content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function check(e) {
    var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);
    var obj = document.getElementById('div');
    if(target!=obj){history.back(-1);}
}
```

Comment: One problem with this solution.  If I click on a div within the dumbBox, then it closes, since I didn't technically click on the div with id="div".  This is why I was hoping for a syntactically positive solution like the one I attempted.

Comment: I figured out that adding `onclick="event.stopPropagation ? event.stopPropagation() : (event.cancelBubble=true);"` to the dumbBox div prevents clicks in that div from bubbling up to the vertical-offset div.  So, the code altogether works in Chrome, but your javascript isn't working in Firefox still.